# Get cart contents from my custom module

Tags: cart, quote, quoteitem, sales-quote

In my magento, I have added a product to cart - so I see the following on the checkout page:

[image]

I have a custom module with a `TestController` with a `IndexAction` where I want to retrieve the current contents of basket for custom processing. This will be used to provide a "get delivery cost estimate" type functionality.

I.e. customer will add bunch of items into basket (as guest), click a button on front end and it takes them to our module where they will enter the destination country and postcode and we will do some custom processing to let the customer know what the estimated delivery cost is going to be.

I tried to retrieve the basket contents like this:

```
$cart_contents = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart_contents->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
   var_dump($item->getName());
}
exit;
```

This does not return anything.

I also tried a different approach:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
exit;
```

This is also returning nothing.

Bear in mind; this is a guest checkout (i.e. customer is not logged in).

To test there is a valid quote; I did the following:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getData());
echo "<hr>";
print_r(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getData());
exit;
```

This is what I get back:

```
Array
(
    [store_id] => 5
    [is_checkout_cart] => 1
    [remote_ip] => 90.xxx.xxx.xxx
    [x_forwarded_for] => 90.xxx.xxx.xxx
)
Array
(
    [store_id] => 5
    [is_checkout_cart] => 1
    [remote_ip] => 90.xxx.xxx.xxx
    [x_forwarded_for] => 90.xxx.xxx.xxx
)
```

Answer (score 0):

tested code try it

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

  if($cart->getAllItems()):

          foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item):
           echo $item->getProduct()->getName();
           endforeach;
 endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the model of the class called Mage_Sales_Model_Checkout_Cart.

This is the standard model of the shopping cart that works equally fine both for registered and non-registered users.

Here is the example of the code: 
https://www.gyazo.com/55a4f2d490e2573af8c25ccba2195ef8

This is just a shopping cart: 
https://www.gyazo.com/c23cc7d32598f847a785f7689b1f01bf

And this is the result of the code implementation: 
https://www.gyazo.com/7151712c0af8ff98cf178e6bf94c7a45

Comment: Okay, let me try your method also using `Mage_Sales_Model_Checkout_Cart`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots with the code. Post the actual code.

Comment: Actually never mind, this method is not any different from what `Qaisar Satti` suggested. I have tried this method also and it's returning nothing.